# How to insert an R script into a bash script?

Tags: r, bash

This question is similar to my previous question [How to insert a python program into a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896943/how-to-insert-a-python-program-into-a-bash-script). I am basically trying to achieve the same thing but with R. I tried the following

```
#!/bin/bash

R 1 2 3 4 << EOF 

args<-commandArgs(TRUE)

for (i in args) {

        print(i) 

}

EOF
```

The output (as displayed when ran in R) should be:

```
[1] "1"
[1] "2"
[1] "3"
[1] "4"
```

The method of the answer to my previous question worked fine for python but not for R (which is what I expected). Is there a way to run R code within a a bash script as there is with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version:  Don't do that.

Long version:   Write an R script for which you can use the `Rscript` executable or, if you have it, the `r` one from our [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) package.

While shell scripts seem tempting at first, you will at some point run into issues with variable interpolation and escaping.  Proper R scripts are better -- and the R sources contain a large number of examples.

Example:

```
/tmp$ ./rex.R 1 2 3 4
[1] "1"
[1] "2"
[1] "3"
[1] "4"
/tmp$
```

With this source:

```
/tmp$ cat rex.R 
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
for (i in args) {
     print(i) 
}
tmp$
```