# Passing arguments to a embedded python script in bash

Tags: python, bash

I'm having difficulties passing arguments to a embedded bash script.

```
 #!/bin/bash/
 function my_function() {
 MYPARSER="$1" python - <<END
 <<Some Python Code>>

 class MyParser(OptionParser):
 def format_epilog(self, formatter):
    return self.epilog

 parser=MyParser(version=VER, usage=USAGE, epilog=DESC)

 parser.add_option("-s", "--Startdir", dest="StartDir", 
               metavar="StartDir"
             )
 parser.add_option("-r", "--report", dest="ReportDir", 
               metavar="ReportDir"
             )
<<More Python Code>>

 END
 }

 foo="-s /mnt/folder -r /storagefolder/"
 my_function "$foo"
```

I've read [Steve's Blog: Embedding python in bash scripts](http://bhfsteve.blogspot.se/2014/07/embedding-python-in-bash-scripts.html) which helped but I'm still unable to pass the argument. I've tried both parser and myparser as environmental variables.

Is it as simple as defining $2 and passing them individually?

Thanks

Comment: Where in this code are you even *trying* to read the value?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I am working with a completed python script (a co-workers) but because of portability need to embed into a bash script I wrote. The python script requires me to declare -s and -r to run.

I had thought (perhaps wrongly) that when I called the my_function with the variable it would pass it as "python script -s /mnt/folder -r /storagefolder".

Comment: Maybe that's helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24897057/3776858

Comment: Now, as a separate issue, don't **ever** pass store an argument list in a scalar string variable (which you're doing here). Argument lists belong in arrays, and yes, bash supports them.

Comment: As an aside -- using the `function` keyword in bash is bad form: It's incompatible with POSIX sh, but -- unlike most of bash's incompatibilities -- gives you absolutely no improvement in expressiveness or functionality over the POSIX-standard syntax. Just use `myfunc() {`, not `function myfunc() {`.

Comment: Also, you don't want to use `<<EOF` -- that'll evaluate the heredoc's contents for shell expansions. Use `<<'EOF'` or `<<\EOF` to prevent your shell from messing the code up before it gets to the Python interpreter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- Really appreciate the help and pointers, you helped me in another question at a different point and it really makes a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this rather a lot. Why mess with a parser where

```
value="hello" python -c 'import os; print os.environ["value"]'
```

Or, for a longer script:

```
value="hello" python <<'EOF'
import os
print os.environ["value"]
EOF
```

---

If you need to set `sys.argv` for compatibility with existing code:

```
python - first second <<<'import sys; print sys.argv'
```

Thus:

```
args=( -s /mnt/folder -r /storagefolder/ )
python - "${args[@]}" <<'EOF'
import sys
print sys.argv # this is what an OptionParser will be looking at by default.
EOF
```

Comment: How would you pass multiple values?

Comment: The same way you pass a single value. `a=b c=d python ...` puts both a and c in `os.environ`. And the args example _already_ passes multiple values.